# How to get value from a div with no ID using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am using the Selenium WebDriver Java API on a Java/HTML5 web project. We do not use many IDs, so I am using xPath to isolate values. In the following HTML snippet, when I use my normal method to grab values, the label and the value text are returned.

```
<div class="gf-item col-sm-4"><label>First Name</label>Emma</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to grab just the value ("Emma") using Selenium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the XPath would be

```
//div[@class="gf-item col-sm-4"]/label/following-sibling::text()
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a prettier approach to this.  I would create two selectors.  One that returns only what you want to exclude and one that returns what you want and what you don't.  Then use some Java to compare and remove what you don't want.  I don't do xpath so this is all css selectors.

First, the 'big' selector - returns 'First NameEmma'

```
$$("div.gf-item")
```

Then the 'trim' selector to define what we don't want - returns 'First Name"

```
$$("div.gf-item>label")
```

Then some Java to compare and remove the 'extra' stuff.  This removes 'First Name' and leaves only 'Emma'.

```
    String big = getText(big);
    String trim = getTextText(trim);
    String desiredText = big.replaceAll(trim, "");
```